# CTE recursive query with linq mvc

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, recursion, common-table-expression

My table for Category is something like : `categoryId,cat_name,parentId`

i want to fetch all child categories from root(category) to the bottom of tree in hierarchical form as parent-child relation with linq and also im using mvc3 EF model structure ...

please suggest some solution for this ...

thanks in advance, Milan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to do this without having to write a function to recursively generate a query for each node of the tree, you should consider moving to a nested set architecture rather than a parent/child architecture.  this allows for getting a node an all descendants with one query. read this article on the subject for more information: http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/ (make sure to read the whole thing. the good stuff doesn't start until the second page.)